# How to connect my wired network to the internet via WiFi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Due to reasons..., I can't connect to the internet via my fiber connection. While I wait for someone to come and service the connection, my nextdoor neighbor has said I can use theirs.

However there are two small problems.

1. My tv room is on the far side of the house and the signal is poor (read: poor quality Netflix).
2. We can see each other's Chromecasts.

The first playlist battle was fun, however not accidentally at 12pm when one or the other comes home late.

So what I would like to do is attach some kind of wifi receiver on the neighbor side of the house, connect it to the wired network of the house, and then subnet off each half so the Chromecasts are separated.

Unfortunately I don't know what wifi node features I should be googling for; so I can get the right equipment.

So: 
**What kind of gear and settings do I need to make this work?**

Comment: Would a powerline work?

Comment: @CaldeiraG I don't know what you mean?

Comment: There are converters which allow you to create a network over regular power lines (mains). Usually they're for the HomePlug AV standard, and commonly called "powerline adapters". Not sure if they'll work across houses.

Comment: How much are you prepared to spend for this gear, anyway? One type of device might cost €30 and be unreliable at this distance, another type of device might cost you €300 but work without interruptions for years. (And yes, this isn't a site for specific recommendations, but it seems the general price ranges are the same for most of them.)

Comment: @grawity I'd be happy to spend $100 or so

Answer (score 1):

Could run OpenWRT or pfSense on an old laptop or a Raspberry Pi (one with both Ethernet and Wi-Fi).
Make the neighbour's Wi-Fi the WAN connection (DHCP client), and your wired network the LAN connection.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you want is a **Client Mode** wireless router.

Connect your router via Client Mode to your neighbor's wireless network. This is the ONLY device that connects to your neighbor's wireless network.

The devices on the left are your neighbor's. On the right is your network.

[image: Client Mode]

> https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1323/